# chrome extension in panel window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I had made a chrome extension that changes page content on go the issue is if I have long stuff to add in content I use copy and Paste but the popup closes every-time I open another page.

I know panel are depreciated but I want to have similar feature, open popup in a detached window that stays on top and opens the popup.html.
How can I do that?

Comment: You can't do it in Chrome. A typical workaround is to inject your UI into the page.

Comment: Can you elaborate or give an example

Comment: See examples and documentation for content scripts.